# Can't set elements properly in 100% mid and static size left and right fashion

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up 3 elements, , , and  in one row. The left and right images have set size, the middle is supposed to fill 100% of what's left. For some reason however, while the first img and div are set up properly, the last img flows away to the next line. Also, firebug says the middle  is actually invisible? And has width of 0px, even though i can see the  inside just fine

```
<div>
    <div class="testowyDiv">
        <img src="ikony/strzalkal.png" class="carousel-button-left"/>
        <div class="testowyDiv2">
        <ul class="testowyUl">
            <li><img src="zdjecia/r_hale/1/1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="zdjecia/r_hale/1/2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="zdjecia/r_hale/1/3.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="ikony/strzalkap.png"  class="carousel-button-right"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

with styles:

```
.testowyDiv{
width: 564px;
height: 128px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:15px;
padding-left:53px;
padding-right:53px;
overflow: hidden;
float:left;
}

.testowyUl{
float:left;
padding:0px;
padding-right:5px;
display:inline;
width:1000px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}

.testowyDiv2{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline;
}

.testowyUl li{
display:inline;
padding-left:5px !important;
padding-right:5px;
}

.carousel-button-left{
display:inline;
float:left;
width:53px;
margin-left:-53px;
}
.carousel-button-right{
display:inline;
float:right;
width:23px;
margin-right:-55px; 
float:left;
}
```

Comment: post JSFiddle maybe so we could help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over using `display: inline` and floats.

Here is some some simple css utilizing `position: absolute` (something which should be used sparingly) to set the left and right buttons. Then the centre div is free to do what it needs.

I have coloured the container div blue and the centre div green so you can see where they are sitting.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.buildgp.com/images/arrow_prev.png" class="carousel-button-left" />
    <div class="centreContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="zdjecia/r_hale/1/1.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="zdjecia/r_hale/1/2.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="zdjecia/r_hale/1/3.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.buildgp.com/images/arrow_next.png" class="carousel-button-right" alt="right" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    width: 564px;
    height: 128px;
    padding: 0 53px;
    background: #ccccff; /* blue */
    position: relative;
}
.centreContainer {
    background: #ccffcc; /* green */
    height: 100%;
}
.centreContainer > ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.centreContainer > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.carousel-button-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;
    width: 53px;
}
.carousel-button-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
    width: 53px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJvW4/)**